# suddenly stopped compiling

Tags: errors, miktex

I'm working on multiple chapters of my thesis. One of the chapters **suddenly** has stopped compiling and many warning massages started to appear and i can not view the PDF file "File not found message". I have no idea whats going on. Any help would be much appreciated

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}% example text
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}


\include{resynthesisresults}
\input{tex/resynthesisresults}\newpage\cleardoublepage

\makenomenclature

\printnomenclature

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{REFERENCES}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\begin{singlespace}
\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{twocolumn}
%next line adds the Bibliography to the contents page
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
%uncomment next line to change bibliography name to references
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliography{bib/12345}        %use a bibtex bibliography file refs.bib
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  %use the plain bibliography style
\end{twocolumn}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{singlespace}


\enddocument
```

\input{tex/resynthesisresults}\newpage\cleardoublepage

[image]

```
enter code here
```

Comment: My magnifying glass broke recently: Shall we use ridiculous large screen resolution to get the problem position?

Comment: Delete all auxiliary files and retry to compile...

Comment: It would be beneficial to post an MWE that reproduces your error. But as indicated by the previous comentator, the cleaning of the auxiliary files might also help.

Comment: There's no error message in the screen shot you provide, just almost innocuous warnings.

Comment: @Werner tried did not workout.

Comment: @Richard will do.

Comment: @egreg when i try to view the PDF file i get an error message saying "file not found".

Comment: @Alswied I can understand you have problems, but the information you're providing doesn't help in locating a possible source of the issue.

Comment: @Alswied This is unfortunately not an complete MWE. It is, for example missing the `\begin{document}` part and it should end with `\end{document}`. I would also advise you to remove the `\include`and `\input`and replace them with text from the lipsum package as you see fit.

Comment: What kind of TeX are you using? Within recent memory, MikTeX made some internal changes to its executables, and they may fail if you don't have certain MS dll files, or if your MikTeX update did not include evrything yu need. Mind you, I doubt if this is your problem here, but if you use MikTex and updated it in between working and failing, it's worth looking into.

Comment: @RobtA Just updated MikTeX and every thing is working fine now. ThanX

Comment: @Richard many thanks for taking the time to help me but updating MikTeX seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments: The problem was with Miktex. Sometime in mid-2015, Miktex changed something, and an update performed in a certain time period was incomplete or missing a Windows dll support. The solution is to re-update Miktex, and if necessary add a missing dll or two, if your Windows system is old. Happened to me!